# An emperors daughter who collects her dead fathers body parts?

Tags: hitsugi-no-chaika

I am looking for an anime that had recently came out maybe in the middle of last month. I watched this maybe around that time, but I cannot find it again and had accidentally cleared my history on Firefox.

The synopsis of the story goes like this-

A young girl with perhaps maybe long hear, probably really noticeable eyes is carrying a large coffin which contains a magical weapon/gun presumably similar to perhaps weapons in the RWBY universe. This girl is the daughter of a emperor who ruled the world in fear or tyranny or both.

In episode one from what I remember, she runs into this boy who uses some type of hunter magic. He has a sister who also uses this same type of magic. From what I remember this girl runs into him as she was crawling around behind bushes trying to make her way to a town. When this boy decides to help her, they are attacked by a deer antelope which she eventually kills. Later on she buys this boy that helped her lunch. It so happened to be owned by his own sister who destroys some tables in an attempt to maybe hurt him seriously for not helping out. The girl with the coffin eventually hires them soon after for a job, but doesn't reveal what it is she is looking for.

Later on in the episode she raids a general or very powerful adversary who was there during the battle which defeated her father. I also remember that the boy she runs into comes along with her including his sister. Eventually both brother and sister encounter this man who has the ability to control anything inside his mansion at will and maybe has physic powers too.

It may help but they refer to this adversary as a real mage which would indicate that they may not be actual mages at all but use some type of borrowed magic. At the end of the episode it is revealed that what she was after was her fathers body parts so she could give him a proper burial. The part of her father they obtained in question was the left or right hand of her father. Before they leave the raided mansion, the man insists that it is a source of great power, assumes that they want to sell it and in desperation is willing to pay anything to get it back. Please note that this desperate adversary was soundly defeated after the hand/item was taken out of this vault. After this happened he could not call upon his physic powers. It also was apparent that the hand powered the mansion and his magic potentially.

Finally all I can remember is that after the successful heist on the mansion, they are encountered by a group that wants to prevent the worlds destruction. They are then tailed by them in a truck and eventually escape in mist.

Comment: If it came out last month (and it wasn't an OVA/film), it should be on [this list](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/years/2014/spring).

Comment: Possibly Chaika The Coffin Princess?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, upon further research this sounds like [*Chaika the Coffin Princess*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaika_-_The_Coffin_Princess). The anime came out a month ago in Japan, so it's relatively new (so I'm not completely sure, but [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2014/04/08-1/crunchyroll-to-stream-chaika-the-coffin-princess-anime) did for starters also start broadcasting it online at around the same time.)

The eponymous Chaika is the daughter of [Arthur Gaz](http://hitsugimenochaika.wikia.com/wiki/Arthur_Gaz), who apparently was the former ruler of the Gaz Empire, according to the fan-made wiki. I haven't seen the anime or read the light novels, so I'm not sure, but judging from the list of names he has it seems reasonable to conclude that he was a bit of a tyrant.

Moreover, as might be suggested by the title, Chaika carries a coffin around most of the time. In the first episode, she runs into Toru Akura and his sister Akari, which is consistent with your description.

[Here's](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=15524) the Anime News Network link.

Comment: You're welcome. For some reason a Google search actually did the trick rather well this time, but I guess `princess carrying coffin` does give more distinct results that I'd imagined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I found the answer in just 14mins. This is better than expected. Thanks Maroon.

The anime I was looking for was indeed Chaika The Coffin Princess. Plot synopsis from animenewsnetworks.com.au:

> Toru Acura is a 20-year-old retired soldier meandering through life now that the war has ended. He encounters Chaika Trabant, a 14-year-old sorceress carrying a coffin, and follows her in hopes of finding meaning to his life again. The two travel with Toru's adopted sister, Akari, the employed member of the group and thus Toru's source of income.

This most definitely is it.

[image]

I also found the girl with the coffin. Her name is Chaika. Credits to Maroon.